# How would you design a "Description" input?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, user-experience

At the moment I'm designing an app I will develop. It's somehow of an event app.

By now, when you create an event, it asks for a title and for a description, but I'm not sure how to design it so it looks cool aswell as understandable by users.

[image]

As you can see, title is kinda obvious that it should be brief. But Descripcion (Description) should be obvious that it can be a longer text.

Do you guys have any idea on your mind that might help me?

I don't know if this is the best place to ask this, but I've seen already several questions related, and should fit, I think.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But Descripcion (Description) should be obvious that it can be a
>   longer text.

The only elegant way I can think of, is to make the EditText at least 3 lines tall and set a hint to it. This way the user can see, that there is enough space to write a longer description in it.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Type your Description in here"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="3" >
</EditText>
```

[image]

Comment: so it kinda looks like what I've already designed, but with a hint. Should be enough I think. This is too damn complicated!! Thanks for your feedback.